# Conexão Sql Server Express 2014 com Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, visual-studio, conexão

[image: Tela de Conexão ao servidor]
Não consigo fazer com o q nome do servidor apareça no Visual Studio, estou com o firewall desativado e já verifiquei que o servidor está ativo, me ajudem por favor
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você está tentando acessar um servidor LOCAL?

Comment: Pelo SqlServer você consegue normalmente?